# Where can I find the handling of the character `<` within a #include directive, as mentioned in [lex.phases]/1.3?

Tags: c++, include, language-lawyer

The last sentence in [[lex.phases]/1.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.phases#1.3) follows below:

> The process of dividing a source file's characters into preprocessing
>   tokens is context-dependent. [ Example: See the handling of `<` within a
>   `#include` preprocessing directive. — end example ]

But I couldn't find anything about the handling of `<` in [[cpp.include]](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include). Does anyone know where can I find this?

Comment: I don't get you, it's right there at [`/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/cpp.include#2).

Comment: @YSC The paragraph doesn't say anything about the context dependency mentioned above, which would probably involve the character `<`.

Comment: The context is the rest of the directive, namely `# include < h-char-sequence > new-line`. This is the context. In a different context, e.g. `if (a > b)` the `>` character is handled differently and is a token by itself.

Comment: Per **[lex.pptoken]**, `header-name` is a single preprocessing token. Per **[lex.header]**, one of the forms of `header-name` is `< h-char-sequence >`. Therefore `<` may be a preprocessing token in its own right sometimes, and part of a larger token other times; depending on context.